# How is the `llvm::ilist_iterator<NodeTy>::operator pointer() const` method utilized?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, llvm, llvm-ir

I've found that the implementation of this method was to simply return the pointer stored within the `ilist_iterator` class (http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ilist_8h_source.html#l00195). However, it is unclear to me how this operator is used.

I'm assuming that with that operator, we can do the following.

`...
ilist_iterator<NodeType> it = ...;
NodeType const *node = it;  // rather than &(*it)?
...`

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is precisely what it does. It also allows `it` to be passed as an argument to a function that takes a `NodeType*` parameter. (It feels like it could be a bit dangerous to me, but I can't think of a specific situation where it would be a problem.)

Comment: There are usually restrictions such as the pointer is likely to be invalidated if that item is removed from the list (and thereby `deleted[]`).

Comment: @DanAllen That's true but also holds for `&(*it)`. I was more like the ability of some implicit conversion to call an unexpected function during overload resolution, such as one that expects `++ptr` to get to the next node in the list.

Comment: That's true and could cause particular confusion with iterators with the additional problem that for some containers it works! However the 'is this a pointer I can ++' is a side-effect of the C (and hence C++) type symptom. array/point duality is very powerful but programmers are responsible for understanding what they're handling. With great power comes great responsibility :).